# How to change element width on scroll?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm pretty new at coding, and right now I'm working on a small school assignment where the idea is to create a single serving site.

I want to make a face from the side with a nose that grows - from left to right - (exactly like Pinocchio) when scrolling the page.

Maybe the code I have written will help to explain what I want to do more accurately...

My question is: what should I do to have my nose element fixed centered to the left, and growing more and more to the right when scrolling? When I set the position to fixed my nose element disappears.

This is my source of inspiration/code -> http://jsfiddle.net/95EtZ/11/

Here is my code:

```js
$(function() {
  var Node = $('#container'),
    BaseWidth = Node.width();

  $(window).resize(function() {
    $('#container').css({
      top: ($(window).height() - $('#container').outerHeight()) / 2
    });
  });

  $(window).resize();

  var $scrollingDiv = Node;

  $(window).scroll(function() {
    var winScrollTop = $(window).scrollTop() + 0,
      zeroSizeHeight = $(document).height() - $(window).height(),
      newSize = BaseWidth * (1 - (winScrollTop / zeroSizeHeight) * (2 / 3));

    Node.css({
      width: newSize,
      "marginTop": winScrollTop + "px"
    });
  });
});
```

```css
#added {
  background: white;
  height: 1500px;
  overflow: hidden;
  position: relative;
}

#container {
  width: 600px;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: #567;
  margin: 0 auto;
  position: relative;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="main.css">
</head>

<body>
  <div id="added">
    <div id="container"></div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: You're using `margin: 0 auto`, which causes the element to be horizontally centered. Simply removing this property will place your growing/shrinking container such that it's on the left of the viewport. There is no need to declare a float on it: http://jsfiddle.net/1xqzwd8j/

Comment: Thanks!

Do you know why my element is very "shaky" when I scroll (both in Safari and Chrome), it kinda flickers forwards and backwards. I want to use the height of 100px, and the width of 600px. 

Here's a demo of the problem: http://jsfiddle.net/1xqzwd8j/2/

Any suggestions?

Comment: Unfortunately I am unable to reproduce your issue, I don't see any flickering at all... if you can include a gif to explain the effect you're seeing, that'll be great.

Comment: Sorry but I don't know how to make a GIF out of the website issue. Did my jsfiddle link work without any problem for you?

Could you scroll and resize the element without a "wobbling" effect on the horizontal lines? The vertical line that moves forward and backwards (depending on how you scroll) works just fine for me.

Don't know how to give you more details on the issue. Should I use a different browser? (working in Safari and Chrome, at the moment)

Big thanks for helping me out, Terry!

Comment: When scrolling with the up and down arrows on my keyboard, it works as a charm. But not when I use a mouse or a trackpad...

Answer (score 0):

Just make the div floating left and it should work.

```
#container {
  width: 600px;
  height: 2000px;
  background-color: #567;
  margin: 0 auto;
  position:relative;
  float:left;    
}
```